# Android Webview and SupportMapFragment make app crash with the error: "E/chromium: [...] too few uniforms or varyings supported."

Tags: java, android, webview, chromium, supportmapfragment

I am using a Webview in my app and when the user leaves this screen and enters another screen with a map (SupportMapFragment) as a ChildFragment and then comes back to the screen with the Webview, the app crashes with the following error:

"E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(455)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported."

[image]:

I know it has something to do with the SupportMapFragment because when I replace this ChildFragment with another Fragment the issue no longer appears. I have tried many combinations and the error only occurs when a SupportMapFragment is created.

This happens on the simulator and can be systematically reproduced. I have tried on simulators running Android 9, 10 and 11 (API 28, 29, 30) and have seen the same behaviour.

I have searched for an answer but the only think I could find was an idea that it might have something to do with memory. I have tried releasing the Webview when the user leaves the screen but it hasn't had any effect.

Someone any ideas?

Thanks!